# How to Include Multiple Product IDs in a PHP Action for Woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, hook-woocommerce

How can I modify the code bellow to include multiple product ids ?

```
add_filter('woocommerce_is_purchasable', 'my_woocommerce_is_purchasable', 10, 2);
function my_woocommerce_is_purchasable($is_purchasable, $product) {
    return ($product->id == 100 ? false : $is_purchasable);
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this:

```
function my_woocommerce_is_purchasable( $is_purchasable, $product ) {
    $prod = [ 100, 101, 102 ];
    return ( in_array( $product->id, $prod ) ? false : $is_purchasable);
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately did not work. Thanks anyway

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
add_filter('woocommerce_is_purchasable', 'my_woocommerce_is_purchasable', 10, 2);
function my_woocommerce_is_purchasable($is_purchasable, $product) {
    
    $product_ids = array(100, 200, 300);

    return ( in_array( $product->id, $product_ids ) ? false : $is_purchasable);
}
```